# Sum of elements for tree structure in SQL

Tags: sql, recursion, sum

I've got two tables with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Parts (
   id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
   Name TEXT, 
   Quantity INTEGER, 
   Parentid INTEGER
);  

CREATE TABLE Weight(
   Name TEXT, 
   Weight INTEGER
);
```

The Parts table contains rows for both parent and child parts. 
For a product A there are both several parts (B1 and B2) and subparts (C1-C4):
Contents are something like:
A: 2xB1, 2xB2, 1xC1, 5xC2
B1: 3xC1, 2xC2
B2: 1xB1, 1xC3

and the weight something like:
C1: 5
C2: 4
C3: 2

...or:

```
╔════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Parts                              ║
╠═══════╦══════╦══════════╦══════════╣
║ id    ║ Name ║ Quantity ║ Parentid ║
╠═══════╬══════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║ A     ║ A    ║ 1        ║ NULL     ║
║ B1    ║ B1   ║ 2        ║ A        ║
║ B2    ║ B2   ║ 2        ║ A        ║
║ C1    ║ C1   ║ 1        ║ A        ║
║ C2    ║ C2   ║ 5        ║ A        ║
║ C1    ║ C1   ║ 3        ║ B1       ║
║ C2    ║ C2   ║ 2        ║ B1       ║
║ B1    ║ B1   ║ 1        ║ B2       ║
║ C3    ║ C3   ║ 1        ║ B2       ║
╚═══════╩══════╩══════════╩══════════╝

╔═════════════════╗
║ Weight          ║
╠════════╦════════╣
║ Name   ║ Weight ║
╠════════╬════════╣
║ C1     ║ 5      ║
║ C2     ║ 4      ║
║ C3     ║ 2      ║
║ C4     ║ 8      ║
╚════════╩════════╝
```

In the tables is the weight for the subparts C1-C4 and the quantity of each part.
How do I get the weight for each part and the whole product?

I know it is something with recursive CTE but I'm not able to get the result I want.
I tried it with the help of [Recursive sum in tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394601/recursive-sum-in-tree-structure) but without much success.

This is what I've got:

```
WITH c as (
SELECT Parts.id, 
  Parts.quantity, 
  Parts.id as RootID, 
  (Parts.quantity * Weight.weight) as Weight 
FROM Parts LEFT JOIN Weight ON Weight.name = Parts.name
UNION ALL
SELECT Parts.id, 
  Parts.quantity, 
  c.RootID, 
  (Parts.quantity * Weight.weight) as Weight
FROM Parts LEFT JOIN Weight on Weight.name = Parts.name
  INNER JOIN c on Parts.Parentid = c.id
)
SELECT Parts.id, 
  Parts.parent, 
  Parts.name, 
  Parts.quantity, 
  S.SumWeight
FROM Parts INNER JOIN (
  SELECT rootid, 
    SUM(weight) as SumWeight
  FROM c 
  GROUP BY rootid
) as S on Parts.id = S.rootid 
ORDER BY Parts.id
```

The result I want to achieve is something like:
    A 121
    B1 23
    B2 25

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what does 23 equal for B1 or 121 for A? quantity?  how are you coming up with that?

Comment: Consider using a varchar rather than text for the name columns if you're going to join on them.  Even better, consider joining on integers if at all possible to boost performance.

Comment: B1 = 3xC1 (=3*5) + 2xC2 (=2*4) = 15+8 = 23, weight times quantity. Yes.

Performance is a non issue for me atm, I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear about how weight should be summed in your design to avoid duplicate weight inclusion, but this is an example of working recursion using tables very similar to those you propose.

```
CREATE TABLE Parts (
   Id varchar(20), 
   Name varchar(20), 
   Quantity INTEGER, 
   ParentId varchar(20)
);  

CREATE TABLE Weight(
   Name varchar(20), 
   [Weight] INTEGER
);

insert into Parts (Id, Name, Quantity, Parentid)
values ('A','A', 1, NULL),
('B1','B1', 2, 'A'),
('B2','B2', 2, 'A'),
('C1','C1', 1, 'A'),
('C2','C2', 5, 'A'),
('C1','C1', 3, 'B1'),
('C2','C2', 2, 'B1'),
('B1','B1', 1, 'B2'),
('C3','C3', 1, 'B2');

insert into Weight(Name, Weight)
values ('C1', 5),
('C2', 4),
('C3', 2),
('C4', 8);


WITH a as (
  SELECT x.Id as EndId,
    x.Id as ComponentId,
    0 as ComponentQuantity,
    1 as Lvl
  FROM Parts x INNER JOIN Parts y ON x.Id = y.ParentId -- must have at least 1 child...
  GROUP BY x.Id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT a.EndId,
    x.Id as ComponentId,
    x.Quantity as ComponentQuantity,
    a.Lvl + 1 as Lvl
  FROM Parts x INNER JOIN a ON x.ParentId = a.ComponentId
)
SELECT a.EndId,
  SUM(a.ComponentQuantity) as SumQuantity,
  SUM(a.ComponentQuantity * b.Weight) as SumWeight
FROM a INNER JOIN Weight b ON a.ComponentId = b.Name
WHERE a.EndId <> a.ComponentId
    AND a.Lvl = 2 -- treat 1st child as the weighted subassembly of interest
GROUP BY a.EndId;
```

Comment: Problem is that it doesnt include the weight of the "children" for A (B1 and B2) and B2 (B1).
It only adds the values of C1-C4 but B1 (for B2) and respective B2/B1 for A also have a weight. 
B2 has to weigh B1+C3.

Comment: I disagree; it includes the weight of B1 which should, by definition, include the weight of all components (B2 and so on).  Anyway, play with the last where clause to alter behaviour.  Your logic was not the question; it was the recursion.

Comment: Yes, but B1 is included in B2 but this query returns for B2: 2 and for B1: 23.
But it should Return: B1: 23 and B2:25

Comment: B1 doesn't have a provided value in the Weight table; make the join to the weight table a LEFT join if that matters to you.

Comment: But I could just use 
SELECT parentid, SUM(quantity*weight) FROM parts LEFT JOIN weight ON weight.name = parts.name GROUP BY parentid
for the same (for me wrong) result. B1 has a weight because B1 consists of C1 and C2.
B1 is a part of B2 so B2 has to weigh more than B1.
That is why I wanted to solve it with recursion to calculate the needed values for B1 and B2 (=>weight) and finally A just from the known weight of C1-C4.