# Performing Recursive SQL Query (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this table:

```
ID_Articulo ID_Componente   Tipo    Cantidad
1           5               2       1.5
5           3               1       3
1           6               1       6
2           3               1       3.5
6           8               2       4.2
8           9               1       2
```

I need to find the SUM of Cantidad field for a given ID_Articulo and Tipo=1. For instance, for ID_Articulo=1 should be **1.5*3 + 6 + 6*4.2*2 = 60.9**.

The number to level (deep) are variable for each ID_Articulo.

Can this be donw with a SQL query? My database is SQL Server 2005.

**Aditional info**

Fields ID_Articulo AND ID_Compenente are related to the same table Articulos. Thats why the data is recursive. So, for the given example I have:

```
Rec #1 is not Tipo=1, but relates ID 1 with ID 5
Rec #2 relates ID 5 with ID 3 and Tipo=1 So, I have 1.5 (of Rec #1) * 3
Rec #3 relates ID 1 with ID 6 and Tipo=1, so i have 6
Rec #4 is from another ID
Rec #5 relates ID 6 with ID 8 but Tipo!=1 so i don't sum
Rec #6 relates ID 8 and ID 9 and Tipo=1, so I have 6 * 4.2 * 2
```

**Final solution**

This is the final code (Some field names are different):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT b.ID_Articulo, ID_Componente, Tipo, Cantidad,   
      CAST(Cantidad AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS partialSum
FROM Arbol b inner join articulos a on a.ID_Articulo=b.ID_Componente
WHERE b.ID_Articulo = 2716

UNION ALL

SELECT t.ID_Articulo, t.ID_Componente, t.Tipo, t.Cantidad,
       CAST(c.partialSum * t.Cantidad AS DECIMAL(6,2)) AS partialSum
FROM (SELECT b.ID_Articulo, ID_Componente, A.Tipo, Cantidad FROM Arbol b inner join articulos a on a.ID_Articulo=b.ID_Componente inner join Articulos a2 on a2.ID_Articulo=b.ID_Articulo where a2.Tipo<>'I') as t
INNER JOIN CTE AS c ON c.ID_Componente = t.ID_Articulo
)
SELECT SUM(partialSum)
FROM CTE   
WHERE Tipo = 'I'
```

Thanks @giorgos-betsos for final solution

Comment: I don't see how you get this sum for ID_Articulo = 1 and the sample table you have provided.  I also don't see why this is recursive?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I edit the question to give more info.

Comment: Yes, why is 1.5 * 3 part of your equation?   The only 1.5 is in the first row, where `tipo` is 2, so according to the description, it shouldn't be included.   Your example only makes your question less clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive sum in tree structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394601/recursive-sum-in-tree-structure)

Comment: @TabAlleman Tipo in record #1 is 2, but in the next level (rec #2) Tipo is One, so I need to sum it

Comment: @ericpap, why are multiplying 8 and ID 9? tipo is 1!

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri: rec #6 needs to be sum because Tipo=1. But I cannot simply sum Cantidad, because ID 9 is related to ID 8 by a factor of 2. ID 8 is related to ID 6 by a factor of 4.2. And ID 6 is related to ID 1 by a factor of 6. So I need: 6 * 4.2 * 2 in this case. Remember is a recursive table that related distinct products

Comment: @ericpap, totally unclear. I can not get why did you use 6 twice here `1.5*3 + 6 + 6*4.2*2 `. I can not get when to multiply and when to sum. I can not get where should I place parenthesis in here `1.5*3 + 6 + 6*4.2*2 `.

Comment: As posted your question makes no sense. It is clear to you but to anybody else it is just gibberish. Your rows appear to be somehow related to each other but it is through smoke and mirrors because there is nothing that clearly defines it. In your sample data you don't even have anything that could be a primary key to identify a given row.

Comment: To do something recursively, you want to look at CTE's (Common Table Expressions).  Tab Allerman's link to the question regarding a recurssive sum in a tree structure has a good examples.  CTE's are the "WITH" sections at the top above the query.  They allow you to recursively reference the thing you are creating within itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following recursive CTE to get expected result:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT ID_Articulo, ID_Componente, Tipo, Cantidad,   
          CAST(Cantidad AS DECIMAL(6,1)) AS partialSum
   FROM mytable 
   WHERE ID_Articulo = 1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT t.ID_Articulo, t.ID_Componente, t.Tipo, t.Cantidad,
          CAST(c.partialSum * t.Cantidad AS DECIMAL(6,1)) AS partialSum
   FROM mytable AS t
   INNER JOIN CTE AS c ON t.ID_Articulo = c.ID_Componente
)
SELECT SUM(partialSum)
FROM CTE   
WHERE Tipo = 1
```

What the above recursion does, is that it returns all branches emanating from `ID_Articulo = 1`, along with the cumulative product of the multiplication of `Cantidad` values:

```
 ID_Articulo    ID_Componente   Tipo    Cantidad    partialSum
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1              5               2       1.5         1.5
 1              6               1       6.0         6.0
 6              8               2       4.2         25.2
 8              9               1       2.0         50.4
 5              3               1       3.0         4.5
```

The result is calculated using the `SUM` on `partialSum` *only* for those rows where `Tipo = 1`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/732d0/1)

Comment: You are the man! How is it possible to guess what was required??

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I'm just taking a wild guess. Only the OP can verify if the above solution is what his/her true intention is!

Comment: Very close! I evaluate this with real data and tell you how it goes!

Comment: Yes! After some adapting, it Works great! thanks! I'll post the final result