# Calculate balance sheet with fastest algorithm

Tags: sql, performance, tree, sql-server-2008-r2

I am implementing accounting software.

In calculating the balance sheet of the hierarchical self-referenced topics, please let me know the fastest algorithm

These are my tables:

**Topics** table:

```
TopicID nvarchar(50) -- is Parent Field
ParentID nvarchar(50) -- is Child Field
Description nvarchar(512) 
------------DocumentDetal table
DocumentNumber nvarchar(50)
TopicFK nvarchar(50)  
Debit decimal(18,0)
Credit decimal(18,0)
```

Two tables are related with `TopicID` and `TopicFK` columns, please let me know how I can calculate balance sheet using a SQL stored procedure.

Followin are data samples:

[image: This is Topics Table and Data]

Following are Documents:

[image]

Actually I want following calculation results:

[image]

Comment: Some member here may be good at algorithm, but not in accounting. So could you explain which logic to calculate balance sheet from your tables? **Sample data** and **expect output** is better.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @PhamX.Bach extera info are provided  please help on this.

Comment: Did you mean by putting c# and SQL Server that you want us to write some c# code, or rather SQL? You wrote something about procedure, but the c# tag is a bit misleading

Comment: @JakubSzumiato I want to write sql stored proc and the use the proc in c# but my problem is just sql.

Comment: Why is the sales table hierarchical? I would just make that a sales and a sub sales table. Or can sub sales themselves have sub sales again?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner it is tree and it could have more childs

Comment: Okay then, in your documents table there is no record for topic 010, probably because it's the parent record. Or is this coincidence? What if I have three levels, ID 010 -> ID 010001 -> ID 010001001, could there be document records with ID 010? With ID 010001? Or only with ID 010001001?

Comment: always you have only the last level for use in documentdetail table @ThorstenKettner

Comment: I've tried to find a recursive query solving this, but failed. I think I got as far as producing the desired records, but couldn't get them ordered, which renders the results useless. I'd hence simply select the aggregates per topic ID in SQL and do the rest in the application layer, i.e. C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `SQL Server 2008 R2`, Here is for `sumDebit and sumCredit`. Don't understand how to calculate `Res Debit and Res credit` but I think you could edit to get your `Res value` too.

Anyway, this is using `CTE` thank to `Mikael Eriksson` in [Recursive sum in tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394601/recursive-sum-in-tree-structure)

```
with T as
(   
    select t.TopicID, t.ParentID, sum(d.Debit) as sumDebit, sum(d.Credit) as sumCredit
    from Topics t
    left join DocumentDetail d 
    on t.TopicID = d.TopicFK
    group by t.TopicID, t.ParentID
)
,C as
(
    select T.TopicID,
         T.sumDebit,
         T.sumCredit,
         T.TopicID as RootID
    from T
    union all
    select T.TopicID,
         T.sumDebit,
         T.sumCredit,
         C.RootID
    from T
    inner join C 
    on T.ParentId = C.TopicID
)
select T.TopicID,
       T.ParentId,
       S.sumDebitIncludingChildren sumDebit,
       S.sumCreditIncludingChildren sumCredit
from T
  inner join (
             select RootID,
                    sum(sumDebit) as sumDebitIncludingChildren,
                    sum(sumCredit) as sumCreditIncludingChildren
             from C
             group by RootID
             ) as S
    on T.TopicID = S.RootID
order by T.TopicID
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

Tested OK in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9eecb7/8066)

Comment: your code working but is not fast enough, it executes in 8 sec but mine current algorithm executes in 2 sec

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the query shown just considers parent and children, not grand children and further. But you, @franchesco totti, already have a working recursive algorithm and it takes only 2 seconds, but you consider this too slow and need something faster?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner  `option (maxrecursion 0);` and yes, sql is not good at tree structure calculating, it may be beter if we let c# take the rest, or change implementation of table data maybe?

Comment: @Pham X. Bach: Yes, you are right, CTE C is recursive. Sorry.

Comment: Yesterday I was to lazy too analyze your query. I was puzzled how you got your results ordered, because this is where I failed. It shows you rely on the child IDs being ParentId + extension. If that were not the case you couldn't bring your recursive results in the desired order. This is something that should be pointed out. Good answer, anyway.