# SQL Query to get item sums in hierarchical structure between two tables

Tags: sql-server, sum, common-table-expression, hierarchical

A table T_BudgetCharts is given. It contains a hierarchical structure of items from 1 to Nth level. Only Items on the Nth level have a value assigned. The other items, which are not last level, have a 0 assigend.

Another table, T_Invoice is given. This table contains some bookings which are in the relation to the first table using the BudgetItemID column.

What i need is to write an SQL Query which returns TotalSum of each BudgetItem from T_BudgetCharts - including the sum on each Level, the Booked Sum for each item in the T_Invoice table - (here comes the problem) - including the booked sum on each level in the herarchy, and the difference sum, which is the difference between the first two values.

I am working on SQLSERVER 2008R2...

An image for better understanding is attached. Also SQL dump...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BudgetId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BudgetItemLevel] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BudgetItemCode] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [BudgetItemName] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [BudgetItemMasterID] [int] NULL,
    [BudgetItemBudegtValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,
    [BugedtIdOriginal] [int] NULL,
    [MasterIdOriginal] [int] NULL,
    [BugedtItemStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sysDateTimeCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [sysDateTimeModified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_T_BudgetCharts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ON
INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, N'N/A', N'Not assigned', NULL, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CA5499 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CA5499 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (2, 1, 2, N'N/A', N'Not assigned', 1, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CA5499 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CA5499 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (3, 1, 3, N'N/A', N'Not assigned', 2, CAST(1000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CA5499 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CA7067 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (4, 2, 1, N'N/A', N'Not assigned', NULL, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CA6213 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CA6213 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (5, 2, 2, N'N/A', N'Not assigned', 4, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CA6213 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CA6213 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (6, 2, 3, N'N/A', N'Not assigned', 5, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CA6213 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CA6213 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (7, 1, 1, N'A', N'Category A', NULL, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CA95BA AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CA95BA AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (8, 1, 2, N'100', N'Income', 7, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CAAEAF AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CAAEAF AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (9, 1, 2, N'200', N'Outcome', 7, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CAB852 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CAB852 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (10, 1, 3, N'A.100.1', N'Income 1', 8, CAST(2500.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CADF5F AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CB0545 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (11, 1, 3, N'A.100.2', N'Income 2', 8, CAST(10000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CAF466 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CAF466 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (13, 1, 3, N'A.200.1', N'Outcome 1', 9, CAST(6000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CBB48C AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CBB48C AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (14, 1, 3, N'A.200.2', N'Other stuff', 9, CAST(3000.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CBC7EE AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CBC7EE AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (15, 2, 1, N'T1', N'Money', NULL, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CC2709 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CC2709 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (16, 2, 2, N'99', N'Type A', 15, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CC3E2C AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CC3E2C AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (17, 2, 2, N'98', N'Type B', 15, CAST(0.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CC4E48 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CC4E48 AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (18, 2, 3, N'T1.98.1', N'B 1', 17, CAST(300.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CC698D AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CC698D AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (19, 2, 3, N'T1.98.2', N'B 2', 17, CAST(800.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CC73DB AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CC73DB AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (20, 2, 3, N'T1.99.1', N'A 1', 16, CAST(600.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CC958F AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CC958F AS DateTime))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] ([ID], [BudgetId], [BudgetItemLevel], [BudgetItemCode], [BudgetItemName], [BudgetItemMasterID], [BudgetItemBudegtValue], [BugedtIdOriginal], [MasterIdOriginal], [BugedtItemStatus], [sysDateTimeCreated], [sysDateTimeModified]) VALUES (21, 2, 3, N'T1.99.2', N'A 2', 16, CAST(400.00 AS Decimal(18, 2)), NULL, NULL, 1, CAST(0x0000A68000CCA173 AS DateTime), CAST(0x0000A68000CCA173 AS DateTime))
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_BudgetCharts] OFF

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Invoice](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [InvoiceBudgetingID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OrderNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BudgetID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BudgetItemID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AmountProjectCurrency] [decimal](28, 16) NOT NULL,
    [AmountBudgetCurrency] [decimal](28, 16) NOT NULL,
    [BudgetCurrencyRate] [decimal](28, 16) NOT NULL,
    [Percentage] [decimal](28, 16) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_Invoice] ON
INSERT [dbo].[T_Invoice] ([ID], [InvoiceBudgetingID], [OrderNo], [BudgetID], [BudgetItemID], [AmountProjectCurrency], [AmountBudgetCurrency], [BudgetCurrencyRate], [Percentage]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1, 10, CAST(300.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(300.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(1.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(100.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)))
INSERT [dbo].[T_Invoice] ([ID], [InvoiceBudgetingID], [OrderNo], [BudgetID], [BudgetItemID], [AmountProjectCurrency], [AmountBudgetCurrency], [BudgetCurrencyRate], [Percentage]) VALUES (2, 2, 1, 1, 14, CAST(200.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(200.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(1.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(100.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)))
INSERT [dbo].[T_Invoice] ([ID], [InvoiceBudgetingID], [OrderNo], [BudgetID], [BudgetItemID], [AmountProjectCurrency], [AmountBudgetCurrency], [BudgetCurrencyRate], [Percentage]) VALUES (3, 2, 1, 1, 14, CAST(500.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(100.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(1.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)), CAST(100.0000000000000000 AS Decimal(28, 16)))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_Invoice] OFF
```

**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_Bookings](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [BookingTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [ProjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [InvoiceDate] [date] NOT NULL
     CONSTRAINT [PK_T_Bookings] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[T_Bookings]    Script Date: 09/21/2016 15:06:23 ******/
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_Bookings] ON
    INSERT [dbo].[T_Bookings] ([ID], [BookingTypeID], [ProjectID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, CAST(0xCF3B0B00 AS Date))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_Bookings] ([ID], [BookingTypeID], [ProjectID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (2, 2, 1, CAST(0xCF3B0B00 AS Date))
    INSERT [dbo].[T_Bookings] ([ID], [BookingTypeID], [ProjectID], [InvoiceDate]) VALUES (3, 1, 1, CAST(0xCF3B0B00 AS Date))
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[T_Bookings] OFF
```

**

[image]

So far i have the first part, but cant get the booked sum and the difference...Here is my current query...Hope someone can help...

```
WITH C AS 
(
    SELECT  b.Id,
            b.BudgetItemMasterID,
            b.BudgetItemCode,
            b.BudgetItemName,
            b.BudgetItemBudegtValue,
            b.BugedtItemStatus,
            b.Id AS RootID
    FROM T_BudgetCharts b
    WHERE b.BugedtItemStatus = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  b.Id,
            b.BudgetItemMasterID,
            b.BudgetItemCode,
            b.BudgetItemName,
            b.BudgetItemBudegtValue,
            b.BugedtItemStatus,
            C.RootID
    FROM T_BudgetCharts b
    INNER JOIN C ON b.BudgetItemMasterID = C.Id
    WHERE b.BugedtItemStatus = 1
)

SELECT  b.ID as ID,
        b.BudgetItemMasterID AS MasterID,
        b.BudgetItemCode AS BudgetItemCode,
        b.BudgetItemName AS BudgetItemName,
        s.TotalValue AS TotalValue,
        ISNULL(g.Spent, 0) as BookedSum,
        0 as DifferenceSum --Not implemnted yet..
FROM T_BudgetCharts b
INNER JOIN (SELECT RootID, SUM(BudgetItemBudegtValue) AS TotalValue FROM C GROUP BY RootID) AS s ON b.Id = s.RootID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT BudgetItemId, SUM(AmountProjectCurrency) AS Spent FROM dbo.T_Invoice GRoup By BudgetItemId) AS g ON b.ID = g.BudgetItemID
ORDER BY b.BudgetItemCode
```

Comment: @JohnCappelletti What happened with your answers?

Comment: You just need to add grouping and sums - I think you can use something very similar to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394601/recursive-sum-in-tree-structure

Comment: its a quite bit more complex. The user @JohnCappelletti gave a good answer today here, but i don't know what happened with all the comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: fixed a join condition and a few other details (sorry!)

The following CTE connects each Id as the "root" of a tree containing itself and ALL children from ALL levels).  The query using the CTE rolls up ANYTHING YOU WANT that is based on the group (the Id and all its children).

I tried to make it look just like your picture, but you might still need to adjust it to fit what you need. The key part is using the CTE to define each "group" (each parent and all of its children).

```
WITH C AS 
(
    SELECT  b.Id AS RootId,
            b.BudgetItemMasterID as RootBudgetItemMasterID,
            b.BudgetItemCode as RootBudgetItemCode,
            b.BudgetItemName as RootBudgetItemName,
            b.Id as ChildId
    FROM T_BudgetCharts b
    WHERE b.BugedtItemStatus = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  c.RootId,
            c.RootBudgetItemMasterID,
            c.RootBudgetItemCode,
            c.RootBudgetItemName,
            b.Id as ChildId
    FROM T_BudgetCharts b
    INNER JOIN C ON b.BudgetItemMasterID = C.ChildId
    WHERE b.BugedtItemStatus = 1
)
SELECT 
    C.RootId as Id,
    C.RootBudgetItemMasterID as BudgetItemMasterID,
    C.RootBudgetItemCode as BudgetItemCode,
    C.RootBudgetItemName as BudgetItemName,
    sum(isnull(b.BudgetItemBudegtValue, 0)) AS TotalValue,
    sum(isnull(g.AmountProjectCurrency, 0)) AS BookedSum,
    sum(isnull(b.BudgetItemBudegtValue, 0)) - sum(isnull(g.AmountProjectCurrency, 0)) as DifferenceSum
from C 
inner join T_BudgetCharts b ON b.Id = C.ChildId and b.BugedtItemStatus = 1
left join T_Invoice g ON b.ID = g.BudgetItemID
group by C.RootId, C.RootBudgetItemMasterID, C.RootBudgetItemCode, C.RootBudgetItemName
order by C.RootId, C.RootBudgetItemMasterID, C.RootBudgetItemCode, C.RootBudgetItemName
```

Comment: Your solution is not working. Hierarchical sums are not calculated in BudgetCharts neither in Invoice....

Comment: If i would have additional column in the T_Invoice table which is Type of the transaction, lets say income and outcome - would it be difficult change the query to add this value to the TotalSum for the item of the first T_BudgetCharts table?

Example: If trasactiontype Income then add this value to the sum(hierarchicaly all levels) in first table. Otherwise do it like as it is now...@SlimsGhost

Comment: Not sure I understand clearly, but that sounds like it would involve something like changing `sum(isnull(b.BudgetItemBudegtValue, 0)) AS TotalValue` to something like `sum(isnull(b.BudgetItemBudegtValue, 0) + (case when g.TransactionType = 'INCOME' then g.AmountColumn else 0 end)) AS TotalValue`.  Notice the addition of whatever comes out of the `case` expression, which can be adjusted to include whatever conditions and whatever additive amounts you need. This capability would work the same for any calculation that rolls up the hierarchy of each "parent". Let me know if clarification is needed