# Recursive sum in tree structure where tree structure is a string

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Order items are stored together with category path which comes from a tree structure.
That is, Category 2 is a child to Category 1 and Category 3 is a child of 2 etc.

This is a PostgreSQL database.

```
create table order_item (
    id bigserial not null,
    quantity int not null,
    category_path text
);

insert into order_item (quantity, category_path) VALUES 
(5, 'Category 1'),
(7, 'Category 1||Category 2'),
(3, 'Category 1||Category 2||Category3'),
(9, 'Category 1||Category 2||Category3'),
(2, 'Category 4'),
(11, null),
(4, null);
```

```
select category_path, sum(quantity) from order_item group by category_path order by category_path;

category_path                          | quantity |
---------------------------------------------------
Category 1                             |        5 |
Category 1||Category 2                 |        7 |
Category 1||Category 2||Category3"     |       12 |
Category 4                             |        2 |
<null>                                 |       15 |
```

What I would like to get is column with the quantity including subcategories.

```
category_path                          | quantity | quantityIncludingSubCategories |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Category 1                             |        5 |                            24  |
Category 1||Category 2                 |        7 |                            19  |
Category 1||Category 2||Category3"     |       12 |                            12  |
Category 4                             |        2 |                             2  |
<null>                                 |       11 |                            11  |
```

I found this post that is similar but had no luck. [Recursive sum in tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394601/recursive-sum-in-tree-structure)

I've tried solving this with a CTE but can't seem to get it right.
Any suggestions are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

You have the path of each node already, so there is no need for recursion. A straight-forward approach uses a correlated subquery - or a lateral join - with pattern matching on the path:

```
select oi.*, x.quantity1
from order_item oi
cross join lateral (
    select sum(oi1.quantity) quantity1
    from order_item oi1
    where oi1.category_path like oi.category_path || '%'
) x
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=6117c72544c9bbf631797c3a4ac0f31b)**

Comment: This seems to be on the right track but not all the way.
The issue is the group by clause for category_path which doesn't seem to play well with cross join lateral.

Comment: Solved this by using your sql as a subquery.

`select p.category_path, sum(p.quantity1) from
(
select oi.category_path, x.quantity1
from order_item as oi
cross join lateral (
    select sum(oi1.quantity) quantity1
    from order_item as oi1
    where oi1.category_path like oi.category_path || '%'
) x
)  as p
group by p.category_path`

Comment: After some more testing I found that this group by stuff didn't really work out. The problem is that I have quite a large number of order item rows (>1 million)  which will make the query extremally slow. While there will be no more than <1000 different categories. So what I'm looking for is a way to first perform a group by query and with that result do the lateral join.