# How to SUM all descendants value of every node on a tree table

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Assume I have a Category table (tree format) like below:

[image]

I would like to SUM all descendants value of every node on the table and the expected result like highlighted column as below:

[image]

```
the sum_value of Cat 1 = Cat 1 value + Cat 1.1 value + Cat 1.2 value
```

how to write effective SQL to get the result on every level and node?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this on this tread:  [Recursive sum in tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394601/recursive-sum-in-tree-structure)

Here's one of the solutions modified for you table.  There's lots of discussion on that thread on how it works.

```
with cte as
(
  select a.id, a.value, a.id as rootid
  from a
  union all
  select a.id, a.value, cte.rootid
  from a
  inner join cte
  on a.parentid=cte.id
)
select a.*, s.sum_value
  from a
  inner join (
    select rootid, sum(value) as sum_value
    from cte
    group by rootid
    ) as s
  on a.Id = S.RootID
order by a.Id
```

Here's a fiddle link for it: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdbd7/4)