# SQL Server recursive query using MIN()

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use `MIN()` function in my query to get minimum date from lower level of the tree nodes upward and check the date recursively but can't figure out how to do it using the `MIN` function.

So far I have written this query to get tree hierarchy:

```
WITH cteP AS
(
    SELECT
        WBS, WBSParent, 
        StartActual, 
        HierID = CONVERT(hierarchyid, CONCAT('/', WBS, '/'))
    FROM
        MSP.MSPMAIN
    WHERE
        ISNULL(@Top,-1) = CASE 
                              WHEN @Top IS NULL 
                                  THEN ISNULL(WBSParent, -1) 
                                  ELSE WBS 
                          END
     
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        WBS = r.WBS,
        WBSParent = r.WBSParent,
        StartActual = r.StartActual,
        HierID = CONVERT(hierarchyid, CONCAT(p.HierID.ToString(), r.WBS, '/'))
    FROM
        MSP.MSPMAIN r
    JOIN
        cteP p ON r.WBSParent = p.WBS
)
SELECT
    Lvl = HierID.GetLevel(),
    WBS, WBSParent,
    StartActual  
FROM
    cteP A
ORDER BY 
    A.HierID
```

[image: tree]

[image: Query result]

Sample data

```
insert into MSPMAIN  (WBSParent , WBS , StartActual) values 
                    (NULL, 225, null)
                   ,(225, 2251, null)
                   ,(2251, 22511, null)
                   ,(22511, 225111, null)
                   ,(22511, 225112, null)
                   ,(22511, 225113, null)
                   ,(22511, 225114, null)
                   ,(22511, 225115, null)
                   ,(22511, 225116, null)
                   ,(22511, 225117, 2022-10-23)
                   ,(22511, 225118, 2022-11-01)
                   ,(225, 2252, null)
                   ,(2252, 22521, null)
                   ,(22521, 225211, null)
                   ,(22521, 225212, null)
                   ,(22521, 225213, null)
                   ,(22521, 225214, 2022-12-23)
                   ,(22521, 225215, null)
                   ,(22521, 225216, 2022-08-01)
                   ,(22521, 225217, null);
                   ,(22521, 225218, null);
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results? And NOT in the form of pictures, please.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question `jquery`??

Comment: Miad, do you need to find minimum dates for every level of hierarchy? I don't think so, because it's too easy (add the MIN() column and GROUP BY to the bottom query). Or do you need to compare these minimums for all the nodes? It's easy also, you need to add the second CTE in sequence (with mentioned grouping), and use it in the bottom query. So... where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I get  answer according [Recursive sum in tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394601/recursive-sum-in-tree-structure)

```
  with C as
(
  select 
  T.RowNo,
  T.ID,
         T.StartActual,
         T.ID as RootID
  from MSP.MSPMAIN T
  union all
  select 
  T.RowNo,
  T.ID,
         T.StartActual,
         C.RootID
  from MSP.MSPMAIN T
    inner join C 
      on T.ID_Parent = C.ID
)
select 
       T.RowNo,
       T.ID,
       T.ID_Parent,
       T.StartActual,
       S.MINeveryNode
from MSP.MSPMAIN T
  inner join (
             select RootID,
                    MIN(StartActual) as MINeveryNode
             from C
             group by RootID
             ) as S
    on T.Id = S.RootID
order by T.RowNo
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[image]